# Why can't I access my website using the IP address and port number?

Tags: iis

I'm having a weird issue with a website I have installed on IIS.  I can access it if I go to (ip address)/defaultdoc, but not if I go to (ip address):(port).  I'm running a debugger on my browser, and the only thing it's doing when I try to access the site with the port is pulling a 404 error.  This is really weird to me because the default document for the site is definitely the page that I go to when I pull up the site otherwise.  Does anybody have any ideas why this might be happening?

Edit: I'm suddenly not so sure that the default document is working right.  In IIS, it says that the default document is what I want, but when I run a list config command, I get something entirely different.

Comment: What port number is your site hosted on? What protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) are you using?

Comment: 93.  I've tried using other ports and it didn't work out.  Oh, and I'm using HTTP.

Comment: By default, when you access via IP address alone, it uses port 80 (if HTTP) or port 443 (if HTTPS). So you're saying accessing it via IP address alone worked? Then my conclusion is that your site is actually hosted on port 80 and not on port 93 like you think. Perhaps the 404 is from a different site. By the way, you shouldn't host on port 93. You should use a port greater than 1024, and try to use one that [isn't commonly used for something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). My go to port is 58080.

Comment: I'm already hosting a different site on port 80, though.  And no, it doesn't work with no port.  That brings up the OTHER site.  It does work if I do like http://(ip address)/Folder/Folder/index.html though.

Comment: I did change the port in the site bindings and used the one you suggested.  Still nothing.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question and specifically outline exactly what is working, exactly what isn't, and what about it isn't working. Examples would be helpful.

Comment: I'm unsure what's unclear.  I said that the site works if I use the ip address and the path to the default document, but it does't work if I just use the ip and port.  It's a blank page, and if I use a debugger, I can see a 404 error.